# Get message by id from RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using RabbitMQ with Spring AMQP. I want to send some message to the MQ and then obtain just this one (by ID or something).

Right now I have a listener which receives every message sent to MQ:

```
val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

@RabbitListener(queues = arrayOf(RabbitMqConfig.QUEUE_NAME))
fun receiveMessage(message: Message) {
    logger.info("Received message with body = ${message.body}")

    latch.countDown()
}
```

But how can I get specific message by id? I've read about correlationId but there's no method in the RabbitTemplate class to receive by correlationId.

Comment: messages are published and consumed in a fifo-manner. that means that the filtering-logic has to go into the consumer (which could requeue the messages it's not interested in). To better understand your problem, could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/
This explains well what I want to achieve. I want to return to frontend client request id which he can use to check the status of task in queue.

Comment: have a look at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also an `AsyncRabbitTemplate` which returns a `ListenableFuture<?>` when calling one of its `sendAndReceive` methods.

When the async reply is received, you can store the state in your rest controller (or a database) and the user can query the state.

Comment: Right. That is definitely anti-pattern to try to make a `queue` as a persistent store. JDBC or any other DB is definitely for the state holding and good for periodic checking by some `id`.